# Mocking httpclient multiple times in a single Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, serialization, moq, dotnet-httpclient

Hi I am trying to mock the httpclient, obviously forcing it to give me the result I need. **The problem** is, that in my unit test I have to **mock the httpClient twice**, each with a different response.

```
...
...
            var httpReq = new HttpRequestMessage(
            HttpMethod.Get,
            $"{config["MY_TEST_ENDPOINT"]/site1}");

            var myContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var myFirstModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyFirstModel>(myContent );
...
...
```

which I mock this may:

```
...
myMockedHttp
            .Protected()
            .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
                "SendAsync",
                ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
                ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
            .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Content = new StringContent("[{'id':'0001'," +
                                            "'name':'Jonah'," +
                                            "'street':'Cambridge Street 1234'}]"
                                            )
            })
            .Verifiable();
```

That will give me a response, that I can deserialize and use - giving it an object with 3 members: id, name and street.

And here comes the problem for me - I also in the same unit test have another httpclient-call, but I don't know how to mock it. It goes like this:

```
...
...
            var httpReq = new HttpRequestMessage(
            HttpMethod.Get,
            $"{config["MY_TEST_ENDPOINT"]/site2}");

            var httpResponseMsg = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpReq);

            var myContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var myFirstModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MySecondModel>(myContent );
...
...
```

And initially - if it was the only httpclient-call, I would mock it like this:

```
...
myMockedHttp
            .Protected()
            .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
                "SendAsync",
                ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
                ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
            .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Content = new StringContent("[{'id':'34'," +
                                            "'insurance':'Etx'," +
                                            "'insider':'daily'," +
                                            "'collectives':'4'}]"
                                            )
            })
            .Verifiable();
...
...
```

But obviously I cant... The thing is, I have never tried this situation where I have multiple httpclient-calls that needs to be mocked. As you can see, they respond with different Content, since they are different objects and needs to be handled that way.

Do anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Don't use `ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>()`, which allows for any request. Instead, tell the mock exactly the request you want to mock, and what the response should be for that request.

Comment: @HereticMonkey can you please provide an example of that line?

Comment: It's been a while since I've used Moq, but I remember doing something like `It.Is<HttpRequestMessage>((message) => message.RequestUri.Host.Contains("somesite1"))`

Comment: It works! But using ItExpr.Is instead of It.Is, since have to use .Protected.

Comment: Using Moq for mocking HttpClient results in very messy test code. Just create your own fake response handler class that inherits from HttpMessageHandler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometime setting up a mock may not always be the best approach. Since `HttpClient` really depends on `HttpMessageHandler` you can create a simple one to handle the expected requests

```
class TestMessageHandler : HttpMessageHandler {
    private readonly IDictionary<string, HttpResponseMessage> messages;

    public TestMessageHandler(IDictionary<string, HttpResponseMessage> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        if (messages.ContainsKey(request.RequestUri.ToString()))
            response = messages[request.RequestUri.ToString()] ?? new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        response.RequestMessage = request;
        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

The above handler just uses the URL of the incoming request to find the response in the dictionary. It can be refactored to handle more complex requests if needed, but for a simple request this will serve just fine.

Pass the handler to the client created for the test

```
public async Task MyTestMethod() {
    //Arrange
    Dictionary<string, HttpResponseMessage> messages = new Dictionary<string, HttpResponseMessage>();
    messages.Add("https://somesite1.com/ping", new HttpResponseMessage() {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Content = new StringContent("[{'id':'0001'," +
                                    "'name':'Jonah'," +
                                    "'street':'Cambridge Street 1234'}]"
                                    )
    });
    messages.Add("https://somesite2.com/ping", new HttpResponseMessage() {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Content = new StringContent("[{'id':'34'," +
                                    "'insurance':'Etx'," +
                                    "'insider':'daily'," +
                                    "'collectives':'4'}]"
                                    )
    });

    var client = new HttpClient(new TestMessageHandler(messages));

    //...inject client as needed
```

The client with the custom handler can now be invoked as needed when verifying the expected behavior of the subject under test.

Comment: Hmm.. I get "The given key 'xxxx' was not present in the dictionary' at "var response = messages[request.RequestUri.ToString()] ?? new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);" - Shouldn't it not think about those values, when its a mock?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but it just returns 404 instead. It should return 200? Am I doing anything wrong by changing " var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);" to " var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);"? Then it returns statuscode 200..

Comment: @badaboomskey It would return OK but it wont guarantee that it is the response you wanted. To clarify, is it that you want it to return ok for all other requests than the ones you have added to the dictionary?

Comment: @badaboomskey I have tested this code and it worked for the example URLs provided in your post.

Comment: Hmm.. that's weird.. If I don't write HttpStatusCode.OK instead of .NotFound, I'll get a 404. When changing it to .OK "myContent" (or response.Content) is null in "var myContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();" and it's a copy of your suggested code, I've used.

Comment: @badaboomskey make sure that the URLs called on the client are the same as the ones added to the dictionary

Comment: Ah!! Yes, they have to be 100% the same. Perfect!